# Can secure tabbed form with spring security

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm having trouble with secure form that have two tabs - Login/Register. 
Before adding the register tab it worked. I'm using spring security. 
Is that even possible? 
Here is part of the code: 
jsp:
Index.jsp

```
<div id="dialog">
    <form id="dialogForm" action="j_spring_security_check" method="GET">
        <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#login">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="#register">Register</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="login">
                <jsp:include page="login.jsp"/> 
            </div>
            <div id="register">
                <jsp:include page="register.jsp"/>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

login.jsp

```
    <form:form id="logingForm" action="login" method="GET"> 
    <div id="loginForm" class="ui-widget-content" >
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td align="right" width="100">User:</td>
                <td width="100"><input type="text" name="j_username"/></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td align="right" width="100">Password:</td>
                <td width="100"><input type="password" name="j_password" /></td>
             </tr>
          </table>
          <br>
          <input id="logInButton" type="submit" value="SignIn" />
    </div>
</form:form>
```

register.jsp

```
    <form:form id="mainRegForm" action="register" commandName="registration" method="GET">
    <table align="right" width="300" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td>User Name:<FONT color="red"><form:errors
                path="userName" /></FONT></td>
                <td><form:input path="userName" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:<FONT color="red"><form:errors
                path="password" /></FONT></td>
                <td><form:password path="password" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Confirm Password:<FONT color="red"><form:errors 
                path="confirmPassword" /></FONT></td>
                <td><form:password path="confirmPassword" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Email address:<FONT color="red"><form:errors path="email" /></FONT></td>
                <td><form:input path="email" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Age:<FONT color="red"><form:errors path="age" size="1" /></FONT></td>
                <td><form:select path="age" items="${ageList}"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sex:<FONT color="red"><form:errors path="sex" size="1" /></FONT></td>
                <td><form:select path="sex" items="${mfList}"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Location:<FONT color="red"><form:errors path="location" size="1" /></FONT></td>
                <td><form:select path="location" items="${countryList}"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Register" onClick="submitRegister()"/></td>
            </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

spring-security.xml

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <form-login login-page="/index" default-target-url="/welcome"
        authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
    </authentication-provider>  
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="customUserDetailsService" class="controllers.CustomUserDetailsService">
    <beans:property name="userDao" ref="userDao"/>
</beans:bean>
```

When I pressed the login button to submit the tabbed dialog it redirect me to loginfailed page. I try to debut the CustomUserDetailsService class but its not executed. 
Can you please help me with this problem. 
Thank is advice!

Comment: Have you got any log?

Comment: no. No errors or some warnings.

Comment: Have you tried to debug starting from UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication()?

Comment: I have the jars, but when I debug it show me Source not found. ?

Answer (score 0):

The includes `<jsp:include page="login.jsp"/>` and `<jsp:include page="register.jsp"/>` are nesting a form within a form - which is not valid HTML. The browser may not transmit what you expect - hence the login failed page.

You should remove the outer `dialogForm` declared in `index.jsp` and then edit `login.jsp` and change the action for the `logingForm` to be `j_spring_security_check`

Comment: it is the same. Not working. Interesting fact is that when I click on the register button in the register.jsp it work and I successful add new user to the db. Its the login where I have this problem.

Comment: As well as changing the action of the `logingForm` to `j_spring_security_check` - try changing the form to a regular HTML `<form>` element rather than Spring's `<form:form>` tag.

Comment: I change the form form <form:form> to <form> but noting happen. Will it be valid if I remove the form from the login jsp and put it around the <jsp:include page="login.jsp"/> ?

Comment: It should be valid if you do that (as long as it is not nested) - but it would be best kept in `login.jsp` itself as this is where the input elements live. Still, worth giving it a try.

Comment: I try it but nothing happen. Do you thing the problem can be in my entity. Before adding this tab changes, I had just login form and User object marked with Entity annotation. Now I had to add when initialize the index page new object "registration" from the controller. Can this make the problem?

Comment: @RequestMapping(value="/index", method=RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView initializeForm(){
  ModelAndView result = new ModelAndView("index");
    
  result.addObject("registration", new Registration());

  return result;
 }

Comment: I found the problem. It was very simple one. In the form that I submit, the method needs to be "POST" and I was calling "GET". I simply change it to POST and it worked. 
Thank you all for trying to help me with my issue.
Have a great day!